Changed a failing starter recently, and the CEL that was on soon went away. Could there have been a connection?
Never scanned for codes.
Car is 2005 Camry.
156,000 miles.

To my knowledge there should be no correlation between a starter malfunction and a CEL. There's nothing that the system monitors having to do with the starter. The only way you could know for sure is by reading the codes. There are some strange codes which some manufacturers setup, so there is a remote chance.

The only chance of this throwing a code that I can think of is if the battery charge got low while trying to start the car with a bad starter. Codes will tell.
